# Hibernate strange behaviour for row count projection

Tags: hibernate, count, row, criteria, projection

So I have the following code

```
    DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Component.class);
    subquery.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    subquery.createAlias("files", "files");
    subquery.createAlias("files.review", "review");
    subquery.createAlias("review.observers", "observer", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
    subquery.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("review.owner", user), Restrictions.eq("observer.id", user.getId())));
    subquery.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("review.id"));

    DetachedCriteria subquery2 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ReviewNotification.class);
    subquery2.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    subquery2.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("review", subquery));
    subquery2.add(Restrictions.eq("reviewer", user));
    subquery2.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("review"));

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Component.class);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    criteria.createAlias("files", "files");
    criteria.createAlias("files.review", "review");
    criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("review.id", subquery2));
```

now my problme is that if I do the following I get 2 as a return value (this is correct)

```
    List<Component> list = (List<Component>) criteria.list();
    for (Component reviewNotification : list) {
        System.out.println(reviewNotification);
    }
    return new Long(list.size());
```

but if I do

```
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    return (Long) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

I get 4.

Anyone has any idea why the row count is failing?

I have just tried something else

```
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("id"));
```

and this also works. So does anyone have any idea what is happening? I guess the problem is comming from criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); an I wrong?

thanks for assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems that method setProjection overrides

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

which would explain why return data is not unique